# Где можно взять api(аниме)

Tags: python, json

Программа выдает ошибку ключа, хотя всё проверил и должно быть верно.

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

#Выдаёт ошибку KeyError строка 22

#ввод
inp = input(">>> ") # например one pieace
morf = inp.replace(" ","+").lower()
#перевод на английский
name = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', 
target='en').translate(morf)
print(name)
#подстановка в url 
url=f"https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter[text]={name}"                                                       
r = requests.get(url=url)
#ответ в json
d = json.dumps(r.json())
text = json.loads(d)
#множество для уникальности записей, иначе они дублируются
data = set()
for t in text:
    enTitle = text['data'][0]['attributes']['titles']['en_us']
    jpTitle  = text['data'][0]['attributes']['titles']['ja_jp']
    title = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='ru').translate(enTitle)
    stDate = text['data'][0]['attributes']['startDate']
    edDate = text['data'][0]['attributes']['endDate']
    typeA = text['data'][0]['attributes']['subtype']
    desc = text['data'][0]['attributes']['synopsis']
    descrip = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='ru').translate(desc)
    img = text['data'][0]['attributes']['posterImage']['original']
    ep = text['data'][0]['attributes']['episodeCount']
    lenEp = text['data'][0]['attributes']['episodeLength']
    #добавляем запись во множество
    data.add(str(title) +"\n"+ str(jpTitle) +"\n"+ str(stDate) +"\n"+ str(edDate) +"\n"+ str(typeA) +"\n"+ str(descrip) +"\n"+ str(img) +"\n"+str(ep) +"\n"+ str(lenEp))
#печатаем оезультат
print(data)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: чтобы вам могли помочь, укажите что именно должен уметь ваш поисковик. а иначе люди могут найти минимальное апи (название аниме, например) и вам это не поможет. а человек потратит время

Comment: "хотя всё проверил и должно быть верно" Хреново вы проверили print(text['data'][0]['attributes']['titles']) выдает {'en': 'One Piece', 'en_jp': 'One Piece', 'ja_jp': 'ONE PIECE'}, как мы видем нет ключа 'en_us'

Comment: Хм, понял ошибка происходит из-за того что название написано не правильно и ключ я поменял с en_jp на en.

Comment: Поменял шило на мыло:)

Comment: Ну почти, всё-таки я поменяю сервис на другой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

inp = 'one peace'
morf = inp.replace(" ", "+").lower()
name = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(morf)
url = f"https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter[text]={name}"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.json()

data = set()
for t in text['data']:
    enTitle = t['attributes']['canonicalTitle']
    jpTitle = t['attributes']['titles']['ja_jp']
    title = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='ru').translate(enTitle)
    stDate = t['attributes']['startDate']
    edDate = t['attributes']['endDate']
    typeA = t['attributes']['subtype']
    desc = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='ru').translate(t['attributes']['synopsis'])
    img = t['attributes']['posterImage']['original']
    ep = t['attributes']['episodeCount']
    lenEp = t['attributes']['episodeLength']

    data.add(f'{title}\n'
             f'{jpTitle}\n'
             f'{stDate}\n'
             f'{edDate}\n'
             f'{typeA}\n'
             f'{desc}\n'
             f'{img}\n'
             f'{ep}\n'
             f'{lenEp}'
             )

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

install deep_translator(надо вставить в Terminal,тогда будет работать.Не работает потому что модуля deep_translator
не существует)